# Integrating Spotify into a Titanium Appcelerator project

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, spotify

I have been wondering if it's possible to integrate Spotify into a titanium appcelerator app without using a webview.
Looks like there SDK is only for native iOS apps. Has anyone done this before or heard of a solution for this problem?

The use case is: 
Users can share and edit playlists of others.

Thanks in advance.

Peter

Answer (score 0):

If you know objective c you could create a module of yourself

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/iOS+Module+Development+Guide

Thanks